# Find steady state of continuous time Markov chain

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains, matrix-calculus, markov-process

I have a [Continuous Time Markov Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Continuous-time_Markov_chain) with [transition rate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_rate_matrix) given by the folowing recipe:

Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2 \geq 0$ and $\lambda_N := \lambda_1 + \lambda_2$. 
We denote $e_n$ for the row unit vector of dimension $n$, $\alpha := \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \dots & 0
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\beta := \begin{pmatrix}
0 & \dots & 0 &  1
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $m := S_1 \cdot S_2$.
The transition rate matrix is given by
$$
Q = 
-\lambda_N \cdot I_m + 
\lambda_1 \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
I_{S_2 - c_2} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}
0 & I_{S_1-1}\\
\alpha_{S_1-1} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
& 0
\end{pmatrix}
\\
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & I_{c_2} \end{pmatrix} \otimes 
\begin{pmatrix}0 & I_{S_1 - 1}\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
+
(e_{S_1}^{\intercal} \otimes \beta_{c_2} ^{\intercal}) \cdot \alpha_m
\end{pmatrix}
 + \lambda_2 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
 0 & I_{m-S_1}\\
 I_{S_1-c_1} & 0\\
 e_{c_1} \cdot \alpha_m
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

After analyzing this matrix one can see that its structure is fairly simple as it only has 3 non-zero elements in each row.

The question is simple: I would like to find the steady state of this process (or a way to compute it, or an argument why you think this is virtually impossible to do).

I do know that it can by done by solving $\pi \cdot Q = 0 \mbox{ with } \sum \pi_i = 1$ but I don't really see how to easily solve it in this setting.